# IntelliJ shows "More than one bean of type" error in Maven multi-module project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have the following multi-module Maven project:

MODULE_1

- Contains interface A

MODULE_2

- Depends on MODULE_1
- Contains Class X which @Autowires a bean with type A

MODULE_3 (Spring boot application)

- Depends on MODULE_2
- Contains Class B which implements A
- Configures bean with type X

MODULE_4 (Spring boot application)

- Depends on MODULE_2
- Contains Class C which implements A
- Configures bean with type X

I can start up both applications (MODULE_3 and MODULE_4) through IntelliJ just fine and all the beans get autowired. However in the IDE I get an error in MODULE_2 Class X where I try to @Autowire A. The error is:

> Could not autowire. More than one bean of A type. Beans: b (B.java), c
>   (C.java)

What could I be missing there? I would expect no errors because MODULE_2 has no dependencies on MODULE_3 and 4 and should not even see the implementations, even less try to autowire them.

I have tried Invalidating IntelliJ caches, restarting the IDE and reimporting Maven dependencies through IDE.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Intellij IDEA 2018.3.5
- Oracle JDK 1.8.0_152

Comment: I found a couple of the related (but a bit outdated) issues on JetBrains issue tracker for you: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199421 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191253 . I'd highly recommend to contact them about this (on tracker, or support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea )

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I was just wondering if I was misunderstanding something fundamental and this is the way it is supposed to work.